# Injective and Surjective Function Examples

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble with this problem:

Give an example of a function $f:Z \rightarrow N$ that is

a. surjective but not injective

b. injective but not surjective

Work: I came up with examples such as $f=2|x-1|$ only to realize that it is not injective or surjective.

Comment: Do you mean $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: At least at first, don't look for *formulas*. There is no particular virtue in formulas, just make an accurate description of your function(s).

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot imagine a function that is inject but not surjective which has the domain of $\Z$ and range of $\N$. It is part of my homework.

Comment: Does $\Bbb N$ include $0$?

Comment: Yes I think our teacher allows 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bijection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$:

$$f(x) = \left|2x-\frac{1}{2}\right|+\frac{1}{2}$$

Injections $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$:

$$g(x) = f(2x)\quad \text{ or } \quad g'(x) = 2f(x)$$

Surjections $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$:

$$h(x) = f\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor\right) 
\quad \text{ or } \quad h'(x) = \left\lfloor\frac{f(x)}{2}\right\rfloor$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

Surjective: $f(x)=|x|$

Injective: $g(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is positive, $g(x)=x^2+2$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For surjectivity let $f(x)=|x|+1$

Comment: Or $f(x)=|x|$ if one considers $0$ among the natural numbers.

Comment: Is that a standard thing? I always thought that the naturals do not include $0$?

Comment: I've always thought they do. `;-)`